# Tabla de relación muchos a muchos MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Qué tal, estoy haciendo una base de datos con diferentes tablas las cuales depende linealmente. Acontinuación las muestro.[image: Tablas dependientes]

Dentro de cada tabla pueden existir varias actividades que dependan de otras más.
Las tablas de relación muchos a muchos las acabo de agregar, sin embargo, no sé con qué código crear otra tabla que me diga si un papá tiene varios hijos y que a su ves más de un hijo puede tener el mismo papá.
Las variables que me importan son los id y los Pre (Precedentes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te comento que para el caso de los pades e hijos yo lo veo como una relación de uno a muchos y pudiera quedar del modo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE padres(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    padre_nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    padre_adn VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    padre_direccion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE hijos(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hijo_nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    hijo_adn VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    padre_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_hijos_padres FOREIGN KEY(padre_id) REFERENCES padres(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Y nadamas para mantener el vínculo la lláve foránea es el id del padre que guardo en cada registro que haga en la tabla hijos **(el código anterior es a manera de ejemplo adáptalo si te sirve a tus necesidades)**